Given the total cost of a graph walk, how to estimate the cost of each edge?
I have a real-world problem in which I have a collection of nodes and their edges. This collection is composed of hundreds of nodes and thousands of connections. Then I have about 10 K datapoints each representing a path taken in this graph and the total cost of each path. I'm looking for a function that given the paths estimates the costs for each of the edges.
The real-world scenario is a bit more complicated because the model needs to take into consideration other features such as time, and the input/outputs of each node, so I'm guessing it will need some reinforcement learning pipeline, but the task at any moment depends mostly on the algorithm for what I defined above, and it seems reasonably simple.
Is this problem tractable? And is there already any algorithm in literature to solve it? Because I haven't found one in my full workday of research.

You could try using a regression approach, where you have a column for each of the edges indicating whether/how many times it was visited, and having the total costs as the variable to regress on.

I tried to do something similar already with a sparse matrix representing a system of equations where the columns are every possible edge and the rows are my datapoints. There are then many many methods for solving systems of equations like this, the problem that I ran into is that I can't figure out how to define the boundaries of the system. How many times a variable needs to show up before I can guess it's value? I get that rows with less variables showing up give me more information than those with more, but how much information is gained per row?
